# How to fix when echo link url array in php?

Tags: php

I have a code example:

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
    // convert link url
    function foo($uri) {
        $url = parse_url($uri);
        $paths = explode('/', $url['path']);
        return sprintf("%s://%s/%s", $url['scheme'], 'localhost/test/get_image/images', end($paths));
    }
    $str = '<img src="http://www.somedomain.com/somepic.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.microsoft.com/somepic.jpg" />';
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load($str);
    // remove all image
    $arr_img = array();
    foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
        $arr_img[] = $element->src;
    $str_rep = str_replace($element->src, foo($element->src), $str);
    }
    echo $str_rep;
```

> OUTPUT:

```
<img src="http://www.somedomain.com/somepic.jpg">
<img src="http://localhost/test/get_image/images/somepic.jpg">
```

Error when can't get link "http://www.somedomain.com/somepic.jpg" not convert to "http://localhost/test/get_image/images/somepic.jpg"
How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning something to `$str_rep` in your foreach-loop, but using the variable outside of it: You process only the last match.

Try something like this instead:

```
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
    $arr_img[] = $element->src;
    $str_rep = str_replace($element->src, foo($element->src), $str);
    echo $str_rep;
}
```

Comment: result is : test
<img src="http://localhost/test/get_image/images/somepic.jpg">
<img src="http://www.somedomain.com/somepic.jpg">
<img src="http://www.microsoft.com/somepic.jpg">
<img src="http://localhost/test/get_image/images/somepic.jpg">